# Filter Any Non Alpha Numeric In PySpark

Tags: regex, pyspark, contains, spacy

Using Pyspark and spacy package and have a data set with tokens where I'm trying to filter out any rows that have a token that contains a symbol or non alpha numeric character.

```
the
house
#
was
in
the)
400s
w-ow
$crazy
```

Should only return

```
the
house
was
in
400s
```

I tried using something like
`F.regexp_extract(F.col('TOKEN'), '[^[A-Za-z0-9] ]', 0)` but I want to search the entire token not just index 0. I thought about using a contains() statement but that seems like I would have to do a ton of different or statements to capture all the different symbols I want to exclude

Comment: I think you could use `[^A-Za-z0-9]` as the pattern `[^[A-Za-z0-9] ]` would match any char except the listed in the character class followed by a space and `]`

Comment: That makes sense. Still not sure how to use `regexp_extract` function though to search through the entire token string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

check this out. you can use `rlike` function and use `negation(~)` at the filter.

```
   from pyspark.sql import functions as F

    #INPUT DF
    +------+
    |  text|
    +------+
    |   the|
    | house|
    |     #|
    |   was|
    |    in|
    |  the)|
    |  400s|
    |  w-ow|
    |$crazy|
    +------+

    df.filter(~F.col("text").rlike("[^0-9A-Za-z]")).show()

    #OUTPUT DF
    # +-----+
    # | text|
    # +-----+
    # |  the|
    # |house|
    # |  was|
    # |   in|
    # | 400s|
    # +-----+
```